# How to robustly identify $\arg \min_{x}(x^TAx+B^Tx+c)$ when $A,B$ and $c$ are varying?

Tags: matrices, gradient-descent, quadratic-programming

I wish to minimize an expression that looks like this-
\begin{equation}
e=x^TAx+B^Tx+c
\end{equation}
where, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. The problem here is $A$, $B$ and $c$ are varying.
What I have done is, I have constructed a quadratic cost, such as, $J=\frac{1}{2}e^2$ and now using gradient descent,
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=-\eta\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}=-\eta\frac{\partial J}{\partial e}\frac{\partial e}{\partial x}=-\eta e(Ax+B)
\end{equation}
The equation that I have derived above is simple GD and it works for a fixed A, B etc and it gives the minimia, i.e., $x_1^*$. But when $A,B$ and $c$ change, this algorithm doesnt yield new $x^*_2$ as it should be. 
So I want to know, if there is a way to robustly find $x^*$ even when $A,B$ and $c$ change? Any mathematical construct that might help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *does* happen when you change $A$, $B$ and $c$? How are you changing them?

Comment: Why $B$ instead of $b$?

Comment: You will have to solve a linear system of equations before the parameters change too much. Real-time numerical linear algebra sounds interesting.

Comment: In any case you need to make 2 things sure: (1) $A$ should be positive definite; if not then the problem is unbounded and $x$ will diverge. (2) the step size needs to be chosen small enough. For the convex quadratic problem $\min \frac{1}{2}x^T A x$, the step size needs to be smaller than $\frac{2}{L}$, where $L=\rho(A)=\lambda_{\max}(A)$ is the Lipschitz constant of the gradient.

Comment: @Hyperplane, $A,B$ and $c$ change because of changing set point. The $e$ that you see above is nothing but HJB approximation error-- On-policy reinforcement learning. I need to find $x^*_2$ when those $A,B$ and $c$ change.